# UIAlertView message too long

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uialertview, retina-display

I have an alertView that pops up when reachability has detected wifi.  I have both english and french translations of this.  The problem is the french version's text is a bit longer, and I do have some line breaks in there.

When the text is too long, the alertView changes to a white background with a scrollable text view.  Is there any way around this?  The strange thing is that this only happens on retina devices (or non-retina when in landscape, but that makes more sense).  Non-retina devices show the whole message normally.  It seems like retina devices having *more* landscape shouldn't make this happen.

Help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can u add the images 2 plz ...

Comment: Why fight this system? Just use the alertView with the scrollbars.

Comment: In general, UIAlertView is not something you should modify to change the user experience. I have a couple of them looks really ugly in my app, however I didn't find a better way of doing it. You might be able to use popover if that's iPad, but keep it in mind that you need to follow apple's HIG. After all, I think it is not worth doing.

Comment: I wanted to change it for the sake of uniformity.  I have an icon in the background that I wanted to be visible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all retina devices would produce the same results seeing as they have the same amount of screen real-estate. The difference is in pixel density, which means that an object on retina will be the same physical size but will actually be using 4 times the pixels which produces a much clearer and sharper image.

Secondly, there is no way you can avoid this. `UIAlertView` is a class that Apple allows VERY little customization of, so you may be better off making a custom view and presenting it yourself. This is probably only happening in landscape mode because the alert gets less screen area under these circumstances.

So overall, I would recommend that you either create your own custom pop-up or you trim down the amount of text you're displaying in the alert.

Comment: Thanks very much.  I just needed some confirmation.